# Generating SQL query with given number of rows in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I need to turn my table to this given output table using the column order table. 
Is this even possible using SQL only?

I looked up the answer on the internet and I've seen people generally use `PIVOT`. However, my table has as many columns as there are rows in the column order row. So is this possible?

Any ideas/hints on how to do this are greatly appreciated.

Table I already have (yes, it's sorted by A)

```
         A          B                      C
---------- ---------- ----------------------
         1          1                     74
         1          2                     95
         2          1                     78
         2          2                     10
         2          3                     33
```

Order of Columns (another table I have)

```
   B
-----
   2
   1
   3
```

Wanted table (sorted by A)

```
A   COLUMN 2 COLUMN 1   COLUMN 3
--------------------------------
1     95       74         0
2     10       78         33
```

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  `B` does not represent any ordering.

Comment: `B` represents in which order you select columns. This means, you need to fetch `B` then use the result to build your `select` query.

Comment: Add a column in the 2nd table, something like id with values: 1,2 and 3 that will represent the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out, you need a column in the Order of Columns table representing the order. Assume that column is `id`, then you can use query:

```
select t.A, 
    ifnull(max(if (o.id=1, t.c, null)),0),
    ifnull(max(if (o.id=2, t.c, null)),0),
    ifnull(max(if (o.id=3, t.c, null)),0)
from t
  join t_order o on o.b=t.b
group by t.A
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g8UqEaWZgjCHBbSfbTn7Xd/0)

Comment: Thank you! I'll look up everything you wrote down to try and understand :)